# Xamarin Studio Profile for Moq and Mvvmcross.Test

Tags: moq, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

Trying to follow the instructions for the test pcl from https://mvvmcross.com/docs/testing

```
For a basic .Net 4.5 test setup for, for example, a ViewModel, you can:
create a .Net 4.5 library project
use Nuget to add references to NUnit and to Moq
use Nuget or a local binary folder to add references to all of:
MvvmCross.Core
MvvmCross
MvvmCross.Tests
```

**Moq does not install** -> Could not install package 'Moq 4.2.1510.2205'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarintvos10+xamarinwatchos10+xamarinios10'

**MvvmCross.Tests does not install** ->Could not install package 'MvvmCross.Tests 4.1.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarintvos10+xamarinwatchos10+xamarinios10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I have tried different profile 78, 259, 158. They all have this same error.

Thoughts?

---

Edit in Xamarin Studio I created a Class project

[image: Xamarin Studio Class Project]

However I'm still getting the following errors:

Could not install package '**Moq 4.2.1510.2205**'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Could not install package '**MvvmCross.Tests 4.1.4**'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

---

Another edit

Also tried the Unit Test App that includes nunitlite, but having the same problem.

[image: Xamarin Studio Unit Test App]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Moq NuGet package only contains assemblies for .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0.

The MvvmCross.Tests NuGet package only contains assemblies for .NET 4.5.

So neither of the above NuGet packages can be installed into a PCL project, nor into any Xamarin project.

These two NuGet packages are meant to be installed into a NUnit Library project, in the category Other - .NET, that Xamarin Studio provides and used for testing. The NUnit Library project will target .NET 4.5 and include the NUnit NuGet package for testing.

Comment: Excellent! Is there any documentation on this or was it just trial and error?

Comment: I had a look at what was in the NuGet packages. Moq is for unit testing so it only supports .NET framework projects. MvvmCross.Tests seems to be the same.

Comment: Interesting. I'm still rather new to Xamarin and C# environment and didn't know how to look at which framework a package supports. Thanks for the information!

Comment: A NuGet package (.nupkg) is essentially a .zip file. So on the Mac if you rename it to .zip you can extract the files and see what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is you are trying to install these nuget packages in a portable class library project (PCL). In order to do testing you need to create a separate class library project that will reference your Mvvmcross core PCL project:

[image]

The `Moq` and `MvvmCross.Tests` nuget packages will then need to be install in this new testing project.

Comment: Updated the question with the results. tldr; I'm still getting the same error. Also, this is with Xamarin Studio so I'm choosing the iOS specific class library.